# Há alguma forma de configurar spring MVC para receber um object com subobject?

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

Tenho em meu projeto um controller que recebe dados via jquery. Mas estes dados são convertidos em um objeto que contem subobject. isto é:

```
class Teste{
    String a;
    String b;
    Test2 teste2;
}

class Test2{
    String c;
    String d;
}
```

No controller tá recebendo com o seguinte codigo.

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/novo",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public Teste cadastrar(Teste teste) {
        System.out.println("\n\n*******************TESTE*******************\n" + teste);
        return teste;
    }
```

Desta forma os dados só são enviados por query params. Assim não consigo passar os subobjetos. A função ajax usada é a seguinte.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/teste/novo?' + jQuery.param(teste),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(product),
    success: function (data) {
        //innerOptionsInHTML(data);
    }
}).done(function () {
    console.log("success");
}).fail(function () {
    console.log("error");
});
```

Dessa forma os subobjetos não são passados ao servidor. Na verdade só começou a ser passado ao usar QueryParams. Antes disso a função enviava com o tipo application_json. Mas mesmo assim não funcionava.

Tudo isto usando spring MVC e preciso passar o subobjetos.

Seria mais interessante se pudesse configurar o Spring MVC para receber o objeto via javascript na forma:

```
{
    a:"a",
    b:"b",
    teste:{
        c:"c",
        d:"d"
    }
}
```

sem o uso de params query.

Comment: O Spring trabalha naturalmente da forma que você está querendo. Se não está funcionando tem alguma coisa errada, talvez no lado cliente ao montar o objeto que é enviado para o controller. Revise o nome das variaveis, porque no exemplo que postou sua classe Teste tem a classe Teste2 e no JSON você criou o subobjeto como teste e não teste2.

Comment: Consegui. Acho que nao tava compilando.